# True/False test: $A\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ is nilpotent. Then $A^2=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> True/False test: $A\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ is nilpotent. Then $A^2=0.$

My Attempt:

True: $A^k=0$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z^+\\\implies m_A(x)|x^k\\\implies x\text{ is the only irreducible factor of }m_A\\\implies x\text{ is the only irreducible factor of }\chi_A(\text{since }\chi_A\text{ and }m_A\text{ have same irreducible factors})\\\implies\chi_A=x^2\\\implies A^2=0$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. You are.${}$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is:

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,▕▔╲ \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,▏▕\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,▏▕▂▂▂\\
▂▂▂▂▂▂╱.┈▕▂▂▂▏\\
▉▉▉▉▉▉.┈┈▕▂▂▂▏\\
▉▉▉▉▉▉.┈┈▕▂▂▂▏\\
▔▔▔▔▔▔╲▂▕▂▂▂$